# Count common characters in two strings - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi how can I get count of letters/numbers available in 2 string values? That also includes spaces and periods. A CTE or a function solution may do. Thanks a lot!

For Example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1.5 FLOZ | 1.5 FLUID OUNCES |
| CBOY | CellBoy |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

Row number 1: 7

Row number 2: 4

Currently Using a function but returns incorrect values.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CountCommonChars] (
@var1 varchar(10), 
@var2 varchar(10)
)
RETURNS INT
AS

BEGIN

declare @i int = 0,
    @s char(1) = '',
    @t int = 0

while @i<=9
begin

set @s = convert(char(1),@i)

set @t = @t + (case when charindex(@s,@var1)>0 
    and charindex(@s,@var2)>0 then 1 else 0 end)

set @i=@i+1

end

RETURN @t;

END
```

Current Output of the function
Row number1: 2
Row number2: 0

I think the function only counts numeric values

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output, Also tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Welcome to SO, Azor. Please make it clear what characters are to be included. Is it `'a-zA-Z0-9 .'`?An example input string and resulting count. Also, what SQL code have you tried? For information on how SO works, see https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @lit don't know if a-zA-Z0-9 includes special characters, but I also need a special character to be included. So far I am using a function, but it returns wrong answers and I think it only handles numeric values.

Comment: Which characters do you want to exclude?

Comment: your function is wrong, why not just take `set @s = SUBSTRING(@var1, @i + 1, 1)` and then check if `CHARINDEX(@s, @var2) > 0`. Also might wanna use NCHARs

Comment: The regex pattern `'a-zA-Z0-9 .' includes lower and upper case alphabet characters, digits, SPACE, and FULL STOP (period).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a correlated subquery, where you can use `GENERATE_SERIES` to break out each value into separate rows per letter, join them together and get the distinct count of the same letter.

```sql
SELECT *,
  CommonLetters = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.letter)
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(t.ColumnA)) NumA
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          SUBSTRING(t.ColumnA, NumA.value, 1)
    ) a(letter)
    JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(t.ColumnB)) NumB
      ON SUBSTRING(t.ColumnB, NumB.value, 1) = a.letter
  )
FROM YourTable t;
```

Alternatively, as noted by @siggemannen, you can use `CHARINDEX` for one side of the join

```sql
SELECT *,
  CommonLetters = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.letter)
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(t.ColumnA)) NumA
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          SUBSTRING(t.ColumnA, NumA.value, 1)
    ) a(letter)
    WHERE CHARINDEX(a.letter, t.ColumnB) > 0
  )
FROM YourTable t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/nc4Lv-og)

For total number of matches, including duplicates, just change it to `COUNT(*)`.

On older versions of SQL Server, you don't have `GENERATE_SERIES`. Use [a numbers generator](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) instead.

Comment: i think CHARINDEX would be an improvement, no need to shred both strings

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately generate_series is an invalid object in my sql server

Comment: Like I said: On older versions of SQL Server, you don't have GENERATE_SERIES. Use a numbers generator instead.